# Connection Strings and Configuration Files

Tags: .net

Currently, I am learning how to configure my .NET projects using configuration file.

According to [MS example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), connection string is represented in config file as `<connectionStrings>` element:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <add name="Name" 
       providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" 
       connectionString="Valid Connection String;" />
    </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

Looked up `<connectionStrings>` element schema in [MS documentation "Configuration File Schema"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fk1t1t0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it is not there. I am missing something ?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having with how your connection string is configured?

Comment: It is inside of `<configuration>`. see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x77e536(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Hopdizzle, my issue: `<connectionStrings>` is a child of `configuration` element. According to what rules it was formed. Is it custom formed field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here in this site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You see, this is a property of the class(and I am aware of `ConfigurationManager` class), what I was curious if it was actually documented as predefined element.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x77e536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx -- check this out, there is not a word about `<connectionStrings>` element